# How to sequence an array of objects based on custom field?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, typescript, data-structures

I have an array which lists certain tasks and the tasks that they are dependent upon. For example:

```
let taskArray = [
{ taskId: 'SR-1', dependsOn: 'SR-2'}, 
{ taskId: 'SR-2', dependsOn: 'SR-5'}, 
{ taskId: 'SR-3', dependsOn: null},
{ taskId: 'SR-4', dependsOn: 'SR-3'},
{ taskId: 'SR-5', dependsOn: null},
{ taskId: 'SR-6', dependsOn: 'SR-2'}]
```

After processing the array should be

```
let sequencedArray = [
{ taskId: 'SR-3', dependsOn: null},
{ taskId: 'SR-5', dependsOn: null},
{ taskId: 'SR-2', dependsOn: 'SR-5'},
{ taskId: 'SR-1', dependsOn: 'SR-2'}, 
{ taskId: 'SR-6', dependsOn: 'SR-2'}
{ taskId: 'SR-4', dependsOn: 'SR-3'},
]
```

The tasks which have dependsOn field as null can be in any order, but the task having dependsOn tasks should be sequenced.

I was thinking of first ordering based on the dependsOn field, that way I will have all the independent tasks at the start, but not sure how to sequence them.

Comment: [Topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)?

Comment: What do you mean by sequence? I mean how do you want to sort the items, alphabetically?

Comment: @NehaSoni not alphabetically, if SR-1 depends on SR-2, SR-2 should come first in the sequencedArray and then SR-1, similarly for all

Comment: @NehaSoni do you mean: always independent task first. then for all depent tasks, the one being depended most will comes first?

Comment: Please pick a language.  `Java` and `Javascript` are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all parent nodes and get a new array based on the root nodes.

[Tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal): [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) in Pre-order, NLR (node, left, right)

```js
const
    getSorted = references => {
        const fn = (array = []) => array.flatMap(o => [o, ...fn(references[o.taskId])]);
        return fn(references[null]);
    },
    data = [{ taskId: 'SR-1', dependsOn: 'SR-2'}, { taskId: 'SR-2', dependsOn: 'SR-5'}, { taskId: 'SR-3', dependsOn: null}, { taskId: 'SR-4', dependsOn: 'SR-3'}, { taskId: 'SR-5', dependsOn: null}, { taskId: 'SR-6', dependsOn: 'SR-2'}],
    references = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        (r[o.dependsOn] ??= []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = getSorted(references);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you like to get each level together, you need to iterate twice, one for the level and another for the children.

Tree traversal: A modified *Depth-first search* with getting the nodes of a parent first and then all children.

```js
const
    getSorted = references => {
        const fn = (array = []) => [
            ...array,
            ...array.flatMap(o => fn(references[o.taskId]))
        ];
        return fn(references[null]);
    },
    data = [{ taskId: 'SR-1', dependsOn: 'SR-2'}, { taskId: 'SR-2', dependsOn: 'SR-5'}, { taskId: 'SR-3', dependsOn: null}, { taskId: 'SR-4', dependsOn: 'SR-3'}, { taskId: 'SR-5', dependsOn: null}, { taskId: 'SR-6', dependsOn: 'SR-2'}],
    references = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        (r[o.dependsOn] ??= []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = getSorted(references);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Does this logic relate to any algorithm?

Comment: yes it has. please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the taskArray into two, sort (or not sort them) and put them back together like below:

```js
let taskArray = [
{ taskId: 'SR-1', dependsOn: 'SR-2'}, 
{ taskId: 'SR-2', dependsOn: 'SR-5'}, 
{ taskId: 'SR-3', dependsOn: null},
{ taskId: 'SR-4', dependsOn: 'SR-3'},
{ taskId: 'SR-5', dependsOn: null},
{ taskId: 'SR-6', dependsOn: 'SR-2'}]

// turn taskId into number e.g. 'ST-1' -> 1 so we can compare them in sort function below
const idToNumber = (id) => parseInt(id.replace('SR-',''), 10)

// independent tasks where dependsOn field is null
let independentArray = taskArray
  .filter(t => !t.dependsOn)
  // as per your question this sorting is optional. comment out if not required
  .sort((a,b) => idToNumber(b.taskId)-idToNumber(a.taskId) ? 1 : -1)
  
// dependent tasks where dependsOn field is not null
let dependentArray = taskArray
  .filter(t => !!t.dependsOn)
  // sort the task by comparing their taskId by extracting the number
  .sort((a,b) => idToNumber(b.taskId)-idToNumber(a.taskId) ? 1 : -1)

// combine them with independentArray comes first
let sequencedArray = [...independentArray, ...dependentArray]

console.log(sequencedArray)
```